# Flutter Row() - Align 3 widgets evenly

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm trying to align 3 widgets inside a `Row()` evenly.
Just it is not working out as I need it to.
I really do not know how to fix this as I have been at it for hours.
I'm sure thet I'm missing something here.
I'm adding my code and a screenshot of current result.

Updated code!

The issue now seems to couse an out of bounds

[New Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxlP5.jpg)

```
Container(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,

  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
  child: Row(

    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,

    children: <Widget>[
      Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[

              Container(
                width: rowWidth * 0.2,
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: randomColor,
                  child: Text('JD'),
                ),
              ),
              
              Container(
                width: rowWidth * 0.2,
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(
                  'John Doe',
                  style:
                      Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                ),
              ),

              Container(
                width: rowWidth * 0.6,
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: Text(
                  'Online',
                  style: Theme.of(context)
                      .textTheme
                      .headline6
                      .copyWith(
                        color:Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      ),
                ),
              ),
              
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: can you add a screenshot of what you want to achieve?

Comment: If I had a screenshot of the desierd result then I would not have made this post.

What I want is really just as the Title says. I want to space `The User IMG` - `The name` and the `Login` text evenly in the row.

Comment: You're getting me wrong. You should have a UI you're trying to reproduce, you can post that UI not that one you've done.

Comment: I don't really have any photoshop skill to just create a visual representation to show you.

I'm tring to explain what I want to do, and the screenshot that I posted is what I have right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it. I modified your Code a bit so you can see it. Your Approach so far was completely fine, you just had to set a width for your Container. Otherwise Flutter doesn't know how to space the elements in the row. Alternatively you could just calculate the width of your Row, and get the width for the Children from that.

I would also recommend putting your Widgets in the Row into Containers for easier handling (like I did below). Hope it helps! Good luck.

```
 Widget _buildTester() {
    final fullWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final rowWidth = fullWidth * 0.9; //90%
    final containerWidth =
        rowWidth / 3; //Could also use this to set the containers individually

    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: rowWidth,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          child: Text('JD'),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        child: Text(
                          'John Doe',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                        child: Text(
                          'Online',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6.copyWith(
                                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                              ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

EDIT:
If you want to position your different Elements more freely, I would give the Containers with your Text/Icon in them a fixed width (Calculated from your Row width) and then you can use the Containers 'alignment' property.

In this example I give the green and grey Containers each 20% of the Row and make their content align to the left, and the yellow Container 60% and align it's content to the right.

```
 Widget _buildTester() {
    final fullWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final rowWidth = fullWidth * 0.9; //90%
    final containerWidth =
        rowWidth / 3; //Could also use this to set the containers individually

    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: rowWidth,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: rowWidth * 0.2,
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          child: Text('JD'),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: rowWidth * 0.2,
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        color: Colors.green,
                        child: Text(
                          'John Doe',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: rowWidth * 0.6,
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                        child: Text(
                          'Online',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6.copyWith(
                                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                              ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: You added a `_buildTester` widget but I still don't get how that is changing anything

Comment: @DalalSamak _buildTester is just a helper function that returns the Widget. It doesn't do anything other than seperate the code from the main build function. If you copied my code and it still doesn't work, there is something further up in your Widgettree messing it up. I'll add a Screenshot of my output.

Comment: Still having issue with this. If I change my question a bit. Is it possible to only push the Login text to the right ?

Comment: @DalalSamak I added another part to my question. I think it should explain what you need

Comment: Please look at the updated screenshot and code above.
I only seem to have an out of bounds issue - otherwise it all works fine

Comment: @DalalSamak There is probably some padding or margin making it so your 3 Containers are too wide. I would just change it to 'final rowWidth = fullWidth * 0.9 - 12.0;'

Comment: Thank you so much for this.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, do like this.

```
Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Text('One'),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('Two'),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('Three'),
                  )
                ],
              ),
```